# Refer to value of enum itself in static method of an enum

Tags: java, enums, static-methods

I have a Java enum with a static method and I want to refer to the value of the enum in the method:

```
public enum SpeedUnits {
    knots { @Override public String getAbbreviation(){ return "kts"; } },
    feetpersecond { @Override public String getAbbreviation(){ return "fps"; } };

    public abstract String getAbbreviation();
    public static SpeedUnits forAbbreviation( String sAbbreviation ){
        if( sAbbreviation == null ) return null;
        if( sAbbreviation.equalsIgnoreCase( "kts" ) ) return knots;
        if( sAbbreviation.equalsIgnoreCase( "fps" ) ) return feetpersecond;
        return null;
    }
    public static int convertToIntegerKnots( int value ){
        if( *** speed-type-goes-here *** == knots) return value;
        if( *** speed-type-goes-here *** == feetpersecond ) return (int)( value * 0.592483801295896 );
    }
}
```

So, for example, I want to call convert like follows:

```
SpeedUnits eMySpeedUnit = SpeedUnits.feetpersecond;
int knots = eMySpeedUnit.convertToIntegerKnots( 80 );
```

How do I refer to the current value of the enum variable within the static method (see *** places in code above) ?

Comment: Have a look at TimeUnit class in JDK for inspiration, it has better design

Comment: @kan I am wary of creating a generic "convert" method, because if I have say, 10 different speed units, then each enum would have a converter to each of the other 9 units, for a total of 90 methods. Also, sometimes the values come in doubles and other times in ints, so I might actually have 180 !!!! methods if I did this. Normally, my software works in one or two standard units, so I only need to convert to the standard units (like integer knots), not every possible unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you invoke the convertToIntegerKnots method on an `instance` of SpeedUnits. And the behavior of the method depends on this instance. So the method should simply not be static, and you can refer to the instance on which the method is called using `this`:

```
public int convertToIntegerKnots( int value ){
    if( this == knots) return value;
    if( this == feetpersecond ) return (int)( value * 0.592483801295896 );
}
```

But it would be much cleaner to define the method as an abstract method, and to override it in every enum instance, exactly as you did with the `getAbbreviation()` method.

Answer (score 2):

There is no current value of the enum in a static method. After you make it non-static you can use `this` to refer to the current value.